# DataGrid's selected row color when inactive

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

How can I style WPF DataGrid to change the color of selected row when DataGrid lost its focus?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find an answer by myself.

Add to DataGrid's resources the brush, which can change its 'Color' property from code behind, and reference HighlightBrushKey to it:

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SelectionColorKey" Color="DarkGray"/>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
        <Style.Resources>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="{Binding Source={StaticResource SelectionColorKey}, Path=Color}"/>
        </Style.Resources>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.Resources>
```

Then add DataGrids event handlers to manually change the color:

```
private void DataGrid1_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ((SolidColorBrush)DataGrid1.Resources["SelectionColorKey"]).Color = Colors.DarkGray;
}

private void DataGrid1_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ((SolidColorBrush)DataGrid1.Resources["SelectionColorKey"]).Color = SystemColors.HighlightColor;
}

private void DataGrid1_LostKeyboardFocus(object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ((SolidColorBrush)DataGrid1.Resources["SelectionColorKey"]).Color = Colors.DarkGray;
}
```

Answer (score 143):

After ages of searching, I found a surprisingly simple way to do this that's cleaner than the Got/LostFocus approach posted earlier:

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}" Color="DarkGray"/>
</DataGrid.Resources>
```

This just sets the inactive background colour to DarkGray, leaving the active background colour to the default, but you can change that too using the SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey too of course.

The foreground resource key for inactive selections is SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightTextBrushKey.

Comment: <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}" Color="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightColorKey}}" /> - Doesn't correct text color

Comment: InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey only works with FW 4.5 and throws an exception with FW 4.0. I wrote more on this http://stackoverflow.com/a/13827971/1815957

Comment: With .NET 4.5 I use this code:
`<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}"  Color="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightColor}"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightTextBrushKey}"  Color="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextColor}"/>`

Comment: how come we need to specify a new value for the SystemColor key 
and not give Background another color like we usually would do ?

is it because the DataGrid overrides the Background color in code ?
or does it have something to do with the fact that our value comes from a static context ?

Comment: InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey isn't available in .net 4.0 :(

Answer (score 29):

Complete solution that works for 4.0.  Note that this on the CellStyle.

```
<DataGrid.CellStyle>
    <!--Override Highlighting so that its easy to see what is selected even when the control is not focused-->
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger  Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}" />
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}}" />
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}" />
            </Trigger>
            <MultiDataTrigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsSelected}" Value="True" />
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGrid}, Path=IsKeyboardFocusWithin}" Value="False" />
                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}" />
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}}" />
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}" />
                </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
            </MultiDataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.CellStyle>
```

Answer (score 10):

Do it like this:

```
<DataGrid ...>
    <DataGrid.Resources> 
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow"> 
            <Style.Resources> 
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Red"/>                                  
            </Style.Resources> 
        </Style> 
   </DataGrid.Resources> 
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It changes selection color. But also for active focus case. So the row always is red neither it is active or inactive. And I need another behavior: _blue_ selected row when DataGrid *has* focus and _red_ selected row when DataGrid *has no* focus.

Comment: @HCL how come we need to specify a new value for the SystemColor key 
and not give Background another color like we usually would do ?

is it because the DataGrid overrides the Background color in code ?
or does it have something to do with the fact that our value comes from a static context ?

Answer (score 8):

None of these answers gave me quite what I was looking for. The top rated by Steve Streeting changed other sections of the datagrid that I didn't want to change, and other answers weren't providing the *inactive* color change, but were properly targeting the row only. So here's a mixture of their answers that changes the *inactive* color, *only* on the rows and not in other places on the grid.

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
        <Style.Resources>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}" Color="DarkGray"/>
        </Style.Resources>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.Resources>
```

Answer (score 7):

**LATE ANSWER:**

This works in **.Net 4.0**, and you don't have to hardcode the color:

```
<Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
    <Style.Resources>
         <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightColor}" />
         <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}" Color="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextColor}"/>
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 4):

For .Net Framework 4.0 (or if you don't want to use the InactiveSelection... brush keys):
Create a **DataGridRow** style/control template, and add these triggers:

```
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <Trigger  Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource SelectionBrush}" />
    </Trigger>
    <MultiDataTrigger>
        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsSelected}" Value="True" />
            <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGrid}, Path=IsKeyboardFocusWithin}" Value="False" />
        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
        <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource InactiveSelectionBrush}" />
        </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
    </MultiDataTrigger>
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

Comment: You may have to do this for the DataGrid.CellStyle instead of the row.  Its still unclear to me when each style is used.

Comment: OK, where does this code go? Within a <DataGrid.RowStyle> or within <DataGrid>. a complete, working answer would be useful.

Answer (score 4):

I added this to my ResourceDictionary so that it applies to all data grids in my program.

```
<Style TargetType="DataGrid">
    <Style.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}" Color="LightGray"/>
    </Style.Resources>        
</Style>
```

Answer (score 4):

You should define section "DataGrid.CellStyle" inside your DataGrid like this:

```
    <DataGrid>
        <DataGrid.CellStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightBlue"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.CellStyle>
    </DataGrid>
```

Comment: But why it's works like that? Why SelectedRow trigger is not enough?

Answer (score 3):

**For .net Framework 4.0**

```
<Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
 <Style.Resources>
     <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="DarkGray" />
     <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}" Color="White"/>
 </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/635642e6-4808-4b3e-8aea-c8c434397d0f/datagrid-lost-focus-brush?forum=wpf

Answer (score 0):

For **.NET 4.0 or higher**: It is also possible to set the colors **programmatically**:

```
if (TestDataGrid.RowStyle == null)
{
  TestDataGrid.RowStyle = new Style(typeof(DataGridRow));
}

// Set colors for the selected rows if focus is inactive
TestDataGrid.RowStyle.Resources.Add(SystemColors.ControlBrushKey, new SolidColorBrush(Colors.SkyBlue));
TestDataGrid.RowStyle.Resources.Add(SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey, new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black));

// Set colors for the selected rows if focus is active
TestDataGrid.RowStyle.Resources.Add(SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey, new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red));
TestDataGrid.RowStyle.Resources.Add(SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey, new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White));
```

For **.NET 4.5 or higher** there is the following alternative to set the colors **programmatically**:

```
if (TestDataGrid.Resources == null)
{
  TestDataGrid.Resources = new ResourceDictionary();
}

// Set colors for the selected rows if focus is inactive
TestDataGrid.Resources.Add(SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey, new SolidColorBrush(Colors.SkyBlue));
TestDataGrid.Resources.Add(SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightTextBrushKey, new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black));

// Set colors for the selected rows if focus is active
TestDataGrid.Resources.Add(SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey, new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red));
TestDataGrid.Resources.Add(SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey, new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White));
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.
The scenario was a DataGrid with colors assigned for:
RowBackground and AlternatingRowBackground.
When the DataGrid Lose Focus, the selected row became Gray, returning to the correct color when the DataGrid regained Focus by clicking on any row.
This effect was unpleasant.
I started from the solution proposed here by Steve Streeting:

```xml
<Style TargetType="DataGrid">
    <Style.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}" 
                         Color="LightGray"/>
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

but by changing Color = "Transparent".

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}" 
                 Color="Transparent"/>
```

this solved the problem in a simple and satisfactory way.
valid for `.net 4.5`, not for `.net 4.0`.

Hope this solution is useful

#### incorrect behavior:

[image: incorrect behavior]

#### correct behavior:

[image: correct behavior]