# .net 4.5: DataGrid - foreground color behavior changed

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, .net-4.5

I've got a c# business application (still targeting .net 4.0). After installing .net 4.5 the inactive foreground color for a datagrid row changed. (i didn't recompile, still executing the same binaries)

It seems that they changed the contrast color calculation for foreground colors.

Some more details. The Datagrid is defined that way:

```
<DataGrid Background="White" AlternatingRowBackground="WhiteSmoke" ... />
```

we also defined a global style for Datagrid that way:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
    <Style.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="{DynamicResource ItemSelectedFocusedColor}"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="{DynamicResource ItemSelectedFocusedColor}"/>
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

The color: `<Color x:Key="ItemSelectedFocusedColor">#88087ED1</Color>`

When executing the app with .net 4 installed, the foreground text color of an **unfocused** Datagrid row is **White**.
When executing the app with .net 4.5 installed, foreground text color of an **unfocused** Datagrid row is **Black**.

If the datagrid has the focus, the behavior is the same. (white in both Versions)

For me, that is a breaking change for an in-place update. All my clients should gain exactly the same user experience independently of the installed version.

I also cannot find any information regarding this issue on [MSDN .net 4.5 Application Compatibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh367887.aspx)

Comment: I would like to help. Could you send me code that reproduces the problem on netfx45compat at Microsoft dot com? Could you also confirm that code works correctly on .NET4.5 and Windows7 but you see issue with .NET4.5 and Windows8? Regards, Varun Gupta, .NET Framework Compatibility Team

Comment: I'm still executing the **same binaries** on Windows 7. First, with .net 4.0 installed and then with .net 4.5 installed. Did't tried it yet on windows 8 and thats even not the point here. Shall I send you the code anyway?

Answer (score 2):

DataGrid and DataGridRow control templates have been changed between .NET4.0 and .NET4.5 versions. Triggers that are responsible for color changeing based on selection and focus do not use the same SystemColors anymore.

This is why overriding SystemColors in xaml to change selection color, even if a nice trick, is not a good practice.

You should override the control templates / style to make them work with your own brushes. That way, even if Microsoft decides to change their built in template, your code won't be affected.

Comment: That well may be. Nonetheless this new behavior is not acceptable for an in-place update. Microsoft cannot expect from me, that i override the control templates of each control used in the application. If I do so, I would have to copy the .net 4.0 framework code too...

Comment: And in fact, i changed the selection color, but i never set the foreground color. So It seems, they changed the color calculation code for the forground colors. So that may has nothing to do with triggers in their template.

Comment: That may have changed Foreground calculation too. Actually I agree on one thing, it's pretty strange that they didnt provide a simple entry point for Selection colors in all their ItemsControl. It's a very common thing in an application to override this kind of thing. That being said, overriding a ControlTemplate/Style is not that hard ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could do it as recommended by @Sisyphe, or you could continue to 'cheat'!
We had to add this to the `Style.Resources` list to fix the same problem

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}" Color="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightColor}"/>
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/13053511/1811110