# Reset inactive selection background color of datagrid

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid

Is there a way to retain the original background color of a row in `DataGrid` when the focus is lost?

I know the `InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey` can set a specific color, but lets say the previous background color could be red or green, I want `InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey`  to be whatever the the original color of the row was?

Added:

I have IsZero property in viewmodel which is true/false, and the below
XAML:

```
          <DataGrid.RowStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsZero}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
                        </DataTrigger>
```

Other rows have other binding to set a different color, but selecting it and deselecting it gives blue and grey colors. I could set the colors, but not sure of an elegant way to set it to whatever the "current background color is."

Comment: How is the original color being set to red or green? Please could you post some XAML showing your situation...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you can use the answer in this page: [DataGrid's selected row color when inactive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7998112/datagrids-selected-row-color-when-inactive) to set the `InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey`  to be `Transparent`.

Comment: Spot on. I couldn't find the answer anywhere else.

Answer (score 1):

Using InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey  is not a good solution (at least for me) as this property is frozen and can't be changed. 
See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.systemcolors.inactiveselectionhighlightbrushkey.aspx

Trying to modify it causes for me a run time error.

In my case using the following worked:

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="Transparent"/>           
</DataGrid.Resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

For WPF 4.0 I found the following worked best as in other solutions the rows still turned gray when i entered another data grid.

```
<DataGrid.CellStyle>
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}}" />
        </Trigger>          
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```