# WPF DataGrid - highlight Selected row even when SelectedItem is a bound property

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I've got a WPF DataGrid where the SelectedItem is bound to a ViewModel property.

```
SelectedItem="{Binding DataContext.SelectedBooking, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
```

If a user clicks on a Row, selecting it, the only visual clue is that the gray background of the row becomes very slightly lighter. I need to make this more obvious, so I tried adding these, individually:

```
<DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

And

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Red"/>
</DataGrid.Resources>
```

The result is the same. When a user single-clicks on a row it very briefly flashes red and then goes back to pale gray, although the Row actually remains as being Selected. If they click on it a second time, it goes red and stays red.

If I remove the Binding on SelectedItem, it works as expected. How can I make this work regardless of the Binding?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the answer myself, scrolling through the Intellisense for SystemColors. There's an InactiveSelection brush that you can override too.

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Red"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}" Color="Red"/>
</DataGrid.Resources>
```

Comment: An amusing little hack here that you can do is also: `<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}" Color="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightColorKey}}"/>`  This will make it so that the inactive is set to active, regardless of default or having to change the highlight key.

Comment: InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey only works with FW 4.5 and throws an exception with FW 4.0. Please check http://stackoverflow.com/a/13827971/1815957

Comment: Thanks for your answer and comments! In my case I had to change the color by combining #Bob and #Khale answers and added: <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="White" /> in order get a contrast for the font. In order words, changed the foreground.