# Change SelectedItem of ListBox from ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, .net-4.0, selecteditem

How can I get the `SelectedItem` of a `ListBox` to be highlighted after setting the `SelectedItem` in the ViewModel?

The `ItemsSource` is bound to an `ObservableCollection` of `Bar` (the collection is a member of a class `Foo`. A button is bound to a command that adds a new empty `Bar` instance to the collection and then also sets `SelectedItem` to the new empty instance.

After adding the instance to the collection, the `ListBox` is updated to show the new blank `Bar`. However, after setting the `SelectedItem` property in the ViewModel, the new instance is not highlighted in the `ListBox` but it is being set and the `PropertyChanged` event is raised (the `SelectedItem` is displayed elsewhere in the View).

Additional Details:

`INotifyPropertyChanged` is implemented in a base ViewModel class, and also implemented in the `Foo` and `Bar` classes.

The `ListBox` contains a custom `ItemTemplate` to display `Bar` members, and a custom `ItemContainerStyle` that modifies the `Background` for the `IsMouseOver` trigger.

simplified xaml:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyFoo.BarCollection}"
         SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedItem, 
                       UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"/>

<Button Content="Add New Bar"
        Command="{Binding Path=AddBarCommand}"/>
```

simplified viewmodel:

```
private Foo _myFoo;
public Foo MyFoo
{
    get { return _myFoo; }
    set { _myFoo= value; OnPropertyChanged("MyFoo"); }
}

private Bar _selectedItem;
public Bar SelectedItem
{
    get { return _selectedItem; }
    set { _selectedItem = value; OnPropertyChanged("SelectedItem"); }
}

private void AddBar()
{
    Bar newBar = new Bar();

    MyFoo.BarCollection.Add(newBar);
    SelectedItem = newBar ;
    _unsavedChanges = true;
}
```

Comment: What is the type of `BarCollection`?

Comment: @Ed `BarCollection` is an `ObservableCollection<Bar>`

Comment: I figured it had to be. With that assumption, your code worked fine for me. Is it possible that the new item is highlighted in a really pale gray color that's scarcely distinquishable from the window around it? The default non-focused highlight background color in modern versions of windows can be perversely hard to notice. If that's the case, it's easily fixable.

Comment: @Ed Ughh... Yes! Changed the ListBox background to white, and the newly added item is indeed highlighted LightGray. Guess I'll override the SystemColor brush? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code worked perfectly for me.

[image]

Notice that "Bar 3" *is* selected, but when the listbox doesn't have focus, the default theme on Windows 7 works pretty hard to keep you from noticing. And Windows 7 isn't even the worst of the bunch. Our application uses `WhiteSmoke` as a default background, and we've had major issues with older users<sup>1</sup> being unable to tell if listbox items are selected or not.

Fortunately, it's a trivial fix. These resources could just as easily be in `Window.Resources`, in a global `ListBox` style, or in `App.xaml`. It's up to you how widely you want to apply them.

```
<ListBox 
    ItemsSource="{Binding MyFoo.BarCollection}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"
    >
    <ListBox.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush 
            x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}" 
            Color="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightColor}"
            Opacity="0.5"
            />
        <SolidColorBrush 
            x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightTextBrushKey}" 
            Color="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextColor}"
            />
    </ListBox.Resources>
</ListBox>
```

---

<sup>1</sup> "Older" meaning old enough to vote.

---

And if your version of .NET predates the existence of `SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightTextBrushKey`, this could probably use some refinement, but it works:

```
<ListBox
    >
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style 
            TargetType="ListBoxItem" 
            BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListBoxItem}}"
            >
            <Style.Setters>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                            <Grid
                                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                >
                                <ContentPresenter />
                            </Grid>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style.Setters>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                    <Setter 
                        Property="Background" 
                        Value="{StaticResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}" 
                        />
                    <Setter 
                        Property="Foreground" 
                        Value="{StaticResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}}" 
                        />
                </Trigger>
                <MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True" />
                        <Condition Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Setter 
                        Property="Background" 
                        Value="{StaticResource {x:Static SystemColors.InactiveCaptionBrushKey}}" 
                        />
                </MultiTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Exactly the issue I was running into. Thanks for the fix! Marked as answer. (sorry not known enough to +1)

Comment: NP, glad to help.

Comment: Overriding the `InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey` did the trick, even though it breaks the Designer in VS2010. [Microsoft docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.systemcolors.inactiveselectionhighlightbrushkey(v=vs.110).aspx) also say the, "brush's `IsFrozen` property is **true**, so it cannot be modified." Is this something to worry about?

Comment: You're not altering the Brush resource; you're just creating a new one with the same key in a more local scope, so `FindResource()` (or whatever is actually doing the job) will find yours first and stop looking. That's unfortunate about breaking the designer, though.

Comment: For anyone else stuck on older .NET frameworks, I came across [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13827971/4681872) that states, "if the system has only .NET FW 4.0, an exception will be thrown when the system create User control with InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey." They recommend setting the color in handlers of LostFocus/LostKeyboardFocus/GotFocus.

Comment: @jonmicjam Oh wow, I forgot about that. Yes, that's a relatively recent one. Should I toss together an ItemContainerStyle that does it the hard way?

Comment: An example may help any others with the same issue. But I'm going to fall back to code-behind, since I assume to do it via XAML would require `EventTriggers` with `Actions` and `Storyboards`?

Comment: @jonmicjam I think it'd just be `<DataTrigger Property="IsFocused" Value="False"><Setter Property="Background" Value="whatever brush" /></DataTrigger>`